# Kubernetes namespaces vs Docker namespaces

Tags: docker, kubernetes, namespaces

Linux kernel offers a feature called namespaces.
Docker containers are isolated with this feature.

There is also a "namespace" feature on kubernetes.
Does it rely on Linux kernel namespaces too ?

Or is it something different ?

Thanks

Comment: By going through these two blogs[1](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/kubernetes-namespaces-demystified-how-to-make-the-most-of-them)[2](https://network-insight.net/2016/03/19/kubernetes-network-namespace). We can say that namespaces is a concept used for isolating the resources and while linux namespaces are used to define which process should access which hardware resources, kubernetes namespaces utilize this capability for isolating the application pods at cluster level.

Comment: Both the blogs explain how kubernetes namespace make use of underlying linux namespace and provide isolation for kubernetes cluster. Contrary to what you said blog2 explains how kubernetes namespaces rely on underlying linux networking modules for providing network isolation to the pods present in that particular kubernetes namespace. Like I said linux kernel namespaces are the bottom layer i.e the kernel, while kubernetes namespaces exists in the top software layer and work along with the bottom layer modules for providing strong isolation in kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Let me explain this in detail for example let's consider the concept of containers, In linux we know that the kernel considers everything as files or processes and for isolating the processes on linux we need linux namespaces. Now if we consider multiple docker containers running on linux as different different processes the only way possible to achieve isolation is by using linux namespaces. We all know that kubernetes is an orchestration software that runs on top of the linux kernel.

Comment: If kubernetes runs on top of linux kernel then it can also be counted as another process, hence for providing isolation between containers we will be using core linux modules which are nothing but linux namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Kubernetes namespaces don't rely on Linux namespaces, they are internal to Kubernetes itself. Linux namespaces are used to isolate each pod. All containers in the pod share the same network, ipc and uts namespaces. Each container within a pod has its own pid and mount namespaces. Pid namespace can be optionally shared between containers within a pod.